# Removing woocommerce short description field

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm creating a theme designed specifically for usage with woocommerce. This theme's design does not utilize the "Product Short Description". Removing that description from displaying on the page was easy enough using:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 20);
```

However, I cannot seem to find any way to remove the field/panel itself from showing to the admin on the product editing pages. If anyone knows how to do that, it would be greatly appreciated. To be clear this is the newer woocommerce 2.0. Thanks!

Comment: can you just add custom Jquery to .hide() the ID or class?

Comment: @RobertLee - Well, I can. Even better I can just add a CSS rule to the admin CSS that will remove it. But WooCommerce usually has actions built in for removing/adding things altogether as opposed to hiding via CSS, and that would be far preferable (as that would be more likely to be maintained during updates than a class name).

But it does seem that that may be what I have to resort to, as nobody seems to know the answer to this. I guess WooCommerce may not have a method built in for this one.

Comment: @RobertLee - Actually, upon inspecting the page I find that the id/class names are rather generic, and I can find nothing in CSS to use to target the product pages only. Using id/classes to hide it would also affect excerpts of blog posts and not just the WooCommerce products. So even that isn't a good option unless you know of some CSS identifiers that would let me single out the WooCommerce products editing pages.

Comment: Would you be able to post the code of the section you want to remove and how it relates to all the other sections on the page you are describing?

Answer (score 12):

You can remove the Short Description field from the WooCommerce admin area via PHP:

```
function remove_short_description() {
     remove_meta_box( 'postexcerpt', 'product', 'normal');
}

add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'remove_short_description', 999);
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Using the 999 priority you will override WooCommerce adding the meta box where they have changed the title and such.

Answer (score 4):

As answered in different treads:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 20 );

function woocommerce_template_single_excerpt() {
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is also what I am looking for. For me, to target the product description's css, use `.single-product .entry-content`.

Until now, I think Woocommerce doesn't provide any hook for product description only.